# Is it possible to display the admin bar while in the Theme Customizer?

Tags: theme-development, debug, theme-customizer

I've been using Debug Bar + Kint Debugger for debugging. Presently I'm working on a custom theme where I'm trying to hook some code into customize_save_after. The code doesn't appear to be running when the theme is saved, so I'd like to be able to access Debug Bar so I can see the variables I'm watching.

Is there any way to force the admin bar to show up in the theme customizer? My search results so far have have been full of people trying to get rid of the admin bar, not make it show up....

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_true');
```

[Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar)

Btw following code in wp-config.php could help also:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); // Or false
   if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // writes errors down in wp-content/debug.log
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );  // shows errors on screen output, set false to on write into logfile
   @ini_set('display_errors',1); // set to zero to disable displaying it and only writing to logfile
   define('SAVEQUERIES', true); // will have a performance impact  so disable if not needed
   define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true); // Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
}
```