# Debugging slow Wordpress Theme Customizer (Any option similar to Query Monitor)?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, theme-customizer

Just wondering what people use for debugging in the customizer?

I use BugFu, Debug Bar and Query Monitor along with Simply Hooks for theme development, but only Bugfu works in customizer and that is not the kind of debugging I need to do.

I tried using this plugin: [Customizer Dev Tools](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-dev-tools/) however, it does not seem to work with the current version of Wordpress.

I am new to theme development, and I have jumped into developing a child theme using the Theme Customizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Query Monitor is, in fact, present in Customizer view. For some reason, I never once scrolled down to the bottom (or just didn't pay attention). Just the debug/admin bar is not visible.

Also, you can do this to get the admin bar in theme customizer:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_true');
```

[Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119047/is-it-possible-to-display-the-admin-bar-while-in-the-theme-customizer)

Another useful tool is [WP Customizer Dev Tools](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customizer-dev-tools/tree/upgrade/4.9) (at this writing, it's only upgraded for up to WP 4.9 on the Git branch. The wordpress.org plugin is outdated)

Keep in mind, Debug Bar and Query Monitor especially can slow down the Theme Customizer tremendously.